# multi thread write only one outputstream and data loss

Tags: java, java-stream, outputstream, fileoutputstream, bufferedwriter

I run the five threads that generate the random string data and then write only one output stream. after the program is finished, a few data was lost.

I simplify my code.

```java
new Thread(() -> {
  stream.write(RANDOM_STRING + "\n)
).start();
```

```java
class Stream {
  String buffer = "";

  Stream() {
    new Thread(() -> {
      BufferedOutputStream bs
       = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("PATH");
      bs.wrtie(buffer.getBytes());  // point 1
      buffer = ""                   // point 2
      bs.close();
    }).start();
  }
  public void write(String input) {
    buffer += input;
  }
}
```

I think data loss's cause is between point 1 and 2. I think If I use the indexing data structure for checking what data was consumed, It can be solved. but is there any better way to solve this problem? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Make ten cards. On five, you write `buffer += RANDOM_STRING + "\n"`, on the other five, write `buffer = ""`. Shuffle them. Pick them one after another and think about the state of the program and the output when they were executed right in that order. Shuffle them again. Look again what would happen when you execute them in that order. Repeat until you understood why using a shared variable in that way is no good, even without discussing the additional gotchas of Java’s memory model. The fact that each thread is overwriting the file doesn’t help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>` for `buffer`, with methods `offer` and `poll` instead of `+=` and `= ""` on String reference.